# How do I hide a navbar on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This has been asked a million times. I have tried every single solution I found here, but none of them worked for me.
I have this navbar:

```
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark hidden-sm" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navToHide">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#quemsou" id="link1">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="link">Link</a>
      </li>
     
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" href="#" id="burguerDrop"><i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size:40px; color:white;"></i></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
    
  </nav>
  </div>
```

And this jQuery/JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 480) {
    $("#navbar").addClass("fixed-top");
    $("#burguerDrop").hide();
  } else {
    $("#navbar").removeClass("fixed-top");
    $("#navToHide").hide();
    $("#burguerDrop").show();
  }
});
```

I can't hide my nav on mobile no matter what. I can't hide the nav or the nav-links. But I can hide and show my 'burguerDrop'. My 'buguerDrop' is working fine, though it's not displaying on my computer web browser. However, it is displaying on mobile exactly how I wanted.

But in the other elements, I can't do the same. I have no idea why. I have tried using both "`css('display', 'none');`" AND "`hide();`". None of them works to hide my navbar, but both of them works to display my `burguerDrop`.

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Hi Júlio Oliveira, I think all you were missing was a call to $("#navbar").hide();. Please let me know if the answer I provided works for you?

Comment: I tried it and it did not worked :<

Comment: you are using bootstrap just use : class="d-none d-md-block" this will hide your element on devices smaller than md

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** As per the other answers and comments this can be done more cleanly with either CSS styling or using built in Bootstrap classes.

To answer your original question: The main thing you were missing is showing and hiding elements in the right places.

I've re-factored your code so you can make use of the [`window.resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event:

```js
function setupMobile() {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 480) {
    $("#navbar").addClass("fixed-top");
    $("#burguerDrop").hide();
    $("#navToHide").show();
  } else {
    $("#navbar").removeClass("fixed-top");
    $("#navToHide").hide();
    $("#burguerDrop").show();
  }
}

$(document).ready(setupMobile);
window.addEventListener('resize', setupMobile);
```

And here is a [demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/aronmarriott-smith/pen/WNpXMyX) to show this solution in action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!!
I literally ctrl+c/ctrl+v your code into mine and it is still not working. I have no idea why. I have little to no other scripts in my project,it is still very small... I think im missing something in my bootstrap navbar

Comment: Hi Júlio, sorry if my original answer did not work. I have update the answer and provided a demo on Codepen for you to checkout. Please let me know if this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is a purely CSS way of doing this. Position sticky basically allows an element to scroll in its parent element. If you want to hide the burger icon you can just do a `display: none` on a media query like below.

```
   #navbar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #burguerDrop {
    display: none;
  }
  
}
```

Here's the codepen for this:
https://codepen.io/jeffteachestheweb/pen/YzZEqRq

Answer (score 0):

Since you already using bootstrap, why dont you simply use css breakpoints.

```
.navToHide {
  display: none;
}
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .navToHide {
    display: block;
  }
}
```